# How to access hidden field using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

Hi I have multiple  elements in my html.Basically using bootstrap carousel.And in all of the  I have a hidden variable called ConsentFormId:

```
<div class="item" id="386">
    <form id="frmConsentForm+386" method="post" data-url="/PP/818003/PatientForms/SaveSignature">
      <input name="ConsentFormId" id="ConsentFormId" type="hidden" value="386" data-val-required="The ConsentFormId field is required." data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ConsentFormId must be a number.">
    </form>
</div>
<div class="item active" id="387">
<form id="frmConsentForm+387" method="post" data-url="/PP/818003/PatientForms/SaveSignature">
      <input name="ConsentFormId" id="ConsentFormId" type="hidden" value="387" data-val-required="The ConsentFormId field is required." data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ConsentFormId must be a number.">
    </form>
</div>
```

Now I need to access the  ConsentFormId hidden field variable of the 'active' form.For that I am able to get the active form by:

```
var $activeForm = $('.active form');
```

Now I need to access the ConsentFormId value  of the active form, which is 387.
I am sure it's a very easy trick, just that am not getting the syntax right, I have been trying many things,none of them worked so far.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are having same ID in both forms. Try to change it and I think you wont have a problem

Comment: `var cfId = $activeForm.find('input[name="ConsentFormId"]').val()` - ID of an element must be unique in a document... in your case use the name of the input

Comment: you can use it via  $('.active form #ConsentFormId').val();

Comment: No they are different, forst one:(which is inactive) is 386, and second one(which is active) is 387; which is what I need.Hidden field variable name remains same in different forms, just that I need the one with active class.

Comment: Thanks @ArunPJohny, it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use same **ID**

By using `ID` you can access value of input element as

`$('.active form input#ConsentFormId').val();`

**or** You can add a class to both input elements... say `"hiddenInput"`. You can access it using

```
$('.active form input.hiddenInput').val();
                or
$('div.active form input.hiddenInput').val();
                or
$activeForm.find('input.hiddenInput').val();
```

**or** by `name` as suggested by `Arun`

Answer (score 0):

Take the active form Id

```
var activeForm = $('.active form').attr('id');
```

Get the input value like

```
$("#"+activeForm+"#ConsentFormId").val();
```

Comment: give spaces before second id

Answer (score 0):

`$('.active form input:hidden')` 
   you can use this. this will give you array . You can loop on this and get the values of the input.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.active form input').val()
```

You can traverse html element using a single space within your jquery selector.